# Does the "sin that dwelleth in me" corresponds to kundalini?

Tags: dualism, christianity, hinduism

In the Letter to the Romans, the apostle Paul writes about "sin" as some entity that dwells in the human body.

Now, I do believe that this entity corresponds to kundalini.

> sin entered into the world (5,12)

The apostle writes about sin not just as an act performed by human beings, but also as some entity that came into the world from outside.

I have read that kundalini dwells dormant at the bottom of the spine until it is stimulated. It then raises through the spine and reaches the brain. Kundalini is a dualistic primordial force. When it raises through the two side channels ida and pingala, it strikes the two cerebral hemispheres producing in the mind a dualistic attitude so that the mind pursues things to be "liked" and things to be "disliked" - in other words it produces in the mind an illusory pursuit of "good" and "evil". This spoiled state of mind pushes the person to seek material pleasures and, at the same time, to innaturally avoid other things.

> Now then it is no more I that do it, but sin that dwelleth in me. (7,17)

> So then with the mind I myself serve the law of God; but with the flesh the law of sin. (7,25)

> Let not sin therefore reign in your mortal body, that ye should obey it in the lusts thereof. Neither yield ye your members as instruments of unrighteousness unto sin (6,12-13)

In this verses it seems that the apostle speaks exactly of this primordial force, kundalini. He recognizes that there is something in his body that pushes him to do things he doesn't want to do. The force Paul is writing about is evidently strong and primordial, connected to lust and libido.

> For when the Gentiles, which have not the law, do by nature the things contained in the law, these, having not the law, are a law unto themselves (2,14)

> What shall we say then? Is the law sin? God forbid. Nay, I had not known sin, but by the law: for I had not known lust, except the law had said, Thou shalt not covet. But sin, taking occasion by the commandment, wrought in me all manner of concupiscence. For without the law sin was dead. For I was alive without the law once: but when the commandment came, sin revived, and I died. (7,7-9)

> For sin, taking occasion by the commandment, deceived me, and by it slew me. (7,11)

Paul writes here about the jewish law. That law is nothing more than a collection of written rules to follow not to incur sin. These rules are also written in the heart of people, but it seems that the jews need them to be written on paper to follow them... But when a jew reads the law, sin takes occasion of the commandment to deceive and slew him. How does this happen? Reading the law, he deludes himself to know the law, producing in his mind the illusion to know the law - to know what is good and what is evil. And it is there that sin, the primordial force, acts in his mind, pushing it to pursue material pleasures. This is exactly how kundalini works in the mind.

> Being then made free from sin, ye became the servants of righteousness. (6,18)

> But now being made free from sin, and become servants to God, ye have your fruit unto holiness, and the end everlasting life. (6,22)

Here the apostle writes about becoming free from sin. This happens when someone frees himself from the dualistic oppression operated by kundalini in his mind, which pushed him to obsessively pursue material pleasures. After that, the person may perform spiritual progress, and when the time is ripe he will be able to tame the kundalini, making it raise through the central channel, sushumna.

Comment: As said by you , please delete the same post at Hinduism SE. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48322/does-the-sin-that-dwelleth-in-me-corresponds-to-kundalini#comment151387_48322

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I was going to do it but now I have got a very useful answer there.